# How do I group multiple windows of an app on a Mac's dock

Tags: macos, dock

I've been a Windows user for many years and have just started using a new Mac. How do I group multiple windows of an app onto the dock? I've searched this site and elsewhere on the Internet and can't find a way. On Windows 10, if you have 5 windows of Chrome open, for example, you can click on the icon in the taskbar and see all of your open windows. I can't figure out how to get the Mac's dock to have the same behavior. Is there a way? I really don't want the dock to be cluttered with icons from opened windows from every app. Thanks.

Comment: This is off-topic. Questions have to be about programming.

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeing windows grouped by application and would rather see the different windows separately, deselect Group windows by application in Mission Control preferences.

[image: Result]

How to add Mission Control to the Dock:

If you’d like a short cut to Mission Control in your Dock but you can’t find it there, here’s how to set it up.

1. Open the Finder
2. Click on Applications
3. Locate Mission Control
4. Rather than clicking on the app, which would activate Mission
   Control, drag and drop it to the Dock

Now Mission Control will be available from your Dock.

How to view all the open windows for a particular app:

[image: Result]

If you have a lot of different apps open and would like to focus attention on a particular app, seeing only the open windows for that app, you can do so.

1. Open Mission Control Preferences (Alt/Option–Mission Control button)
2. Under Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts select the drop down box beside
   Application Window
3. Choose how you would like to activate that feature (e.g. Right
   Option if you want to tap the right Option/Alt key
4. Now when you want to see all the open windows for a particular
   application, select one window for that application and then press
   the key you chose, e.g. Right Option/Alt.